# Create annotated tag with build user

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-repos

I have powershell script which is creating annotated tag for commit in azure repos, but when I run this script in azure release pipeline I got error: "**The combination of parameters is either not valid or not complete."** When I make call from Postman with my credentials. its working. I also set repo permission Create Tag to Allow. Which permission I need for creating annotated tags with build user?

```
$createTagUrl= "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT/_apis/git/repositories/$($env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_ID)/annotatedtags?api-version=6.0-preview.1"

Write-Host "createTagUrl=" $createTagUrl
$jsonObject = @"
    {
        "name": "$($env:RELEASE_RELEASENAME)-$(ENVIRONMENT)",
        "taggedObject":{ 
            "objectId": "$($env:BUILD_BUILDID)"
        }, 
        "message": "test"
    }
"@
Write-Host "JsonObject: " $jsonObject
$json = @($jsonObject) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99

$createdTag = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $createTagUrl -Method Post -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
```

Comment: Hi WMindian, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue:

[image]

The root cause is the code on your side is wrong.

This should works:

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic <PAT>")
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$body = "{
`n    `"name`": `"xxx`",
`n    `"message`": `"xxx`",
`n    `"taggedObject`": {
`n        `"objectId`": `"<object id>`"
`n    }
`n}"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/<Project Name>/_apis/git/repositories/<Repo Name>/annotatedtags?api-version=4.1-preview.1' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```